# Multiple clauses in SQL Server where all columns do not equal zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

Take the example table in `SQL Server`

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
 id1, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
 id2, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00
 id3, 5.55, 2.22, 0.00
 id4, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
 id5, 1.11, 2.22, -3.33
```

I'd like to implement a `WHERE` clause so that when all the values in col2, col3 and col4 equal zero that the line is excluded from the results.

I've tried putting the following `WHERE` clause 
`where col2!=0 and col3!=0 and col4!=0`

This returns only the id5 row, when what I'm after is to return id2, id3 and id5.

I know the where clause is wrong, but not sure what other things to try out.

I've thought about doing a sum across the columns but this isn't desirable, as the decimals can go in either direction and might on the off chance equal zero even when all the values are populated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you intended is:

```
where not (col2=0 and col3=0 and col4=0)
```

interprets as *all rows that don't have all three zero*.

or

```
where col2!=0 or col3!=0 or col4!=0
```

which interprets as *all rows which have at least one of the columns non zero*.